# HTML5 Video - load it muted in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, mp4, mute

I have a video5 implemented using Video for Everyong solution

http://qa.crfhealth.com

I've set the video tag attribute muted="muted" and the flash with attribute 'mute':true

IE is playing the mp4 file, but loads it with the audio playing.

Anyone know how I can mute it for IE9?

Thanks!

Here's the code:

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you already figured this out judging by the date this question was asked, but for whoever might be having this problem, the cause is that IE9 (and earlier versions) does not support the `muted` attribute for the `video` element/tag. The weird thing is, the `muted` property is available via JavaScript. So, digging through MSDN's documentation, I found 3 options to mute/disable the video's audio.

### Option 1: set `muted` to `true`

Set the `muted` property to true, that should do it.

```js
var video = document.getElementById("your-video-id");
video.muted= true;
```

### Option 2: Set `volume` to `0.0`

Set the volume to 0.0 and that's it.

```js
var video = document.getElementById("your-video-id");
video.volume = 0.0;
```

**Note:** if you set the volume value to `0`, it won't work (it didn't in my tests). It must have the decimal point.

You can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more properties with JavaScript at MSDN (but it doesn't say what is supported or what is not supported for IE9).

### Option 3: disable the audiotrack

Option 1 and 2 should be enough, so I didn't test this road, but If you ever need to do this, try this:

```js
/*Note: Only for ilustration purposes.
This code example was not tested, optimized or anything at all.*/

var video = document.getElementById("your-video-id");
var oAudioTracks = video.audioTracks; //returns a list of AudioTrack objects.

for (var i = 0; i < oAudioTracks.length; i++) {  // Step through audio track list
    var audioTrack = oAudioTracks[i]; //  Get tracks
    audioTrack.enabled = false; // disable the track
}
```

References: [AudioTrack object at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Enabled property at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

So, those are the options I've found so far. I hope this are of help.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not visible in your post. Have you tried setting the volume of the player to 0 using JavaScript?

```
var videoElement = document.createElement('video');

videoElement.volume = 0;
```